# Login with Yammer credentials using API

Tags: yammer

I am trying to login website with yammer credentials using REST api. I have registered in yammer API. Now i have got developer token and Client ID from Yammer website.

Could you guys please let me know what is next step to login with yammer credentials from our application using c# in visual studio. Because i am beginner in using API.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

1. The JS SDK approach -
   https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/israelo/2014/10/21/yammer-rest-api-for-dummies/

   2. The ADAL approach -
      https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/israelo/2016/07/05/yammer-apis-and-adal-tokens/

The first open will request users to login via a browser pop up, and the second option can utilise IWA, but there are some pre-conditions and limitations as it is still in preview. Details are in the blog.